# package scala object is not found when two jars are in class path

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jvm

I am facing a strange issue in running my spark app .

**Scenario**

There are two jars which contains same package name (com.example.app). One is my actual code and the other is non-production code which is used for running integration test. I have a package class under the main code which contains type that are used by scala classes in main code. 
  I am creating a context using spark-job server and uploading the test jar first and then main.jar to the server. After running a job in test jar , I am trying to run the job in main.jar which fails with exception saying

```
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object com.example.app.CommonUtils.package not found.
        at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
        at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.ensureModuleSymbol(Mirrors.scala:126) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticModule(Mirrors.scala:161) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
        at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticModule(Mirrors.scala:21) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
```

But when I create a context and upload the main jar alone and run the job in main jar it is working fine.

Which means,
In the spark work dir the job fails when both main and test jars are present then it is failing.
If the main jar alone is present then it is passed.

package.scala

```
src/test/scala/
`-- com
    `-- example
        `-- app
            |-- CommonUtils


    package object CommonUtils {
      type CompositeKey = (String, Int, Int)
      ...
      }
```

**Questions**

- How does the jvm looks for package object in scala ?
- Where this package class should be placed ?
- What is the naming convention for test package ?

Comment: The error was due a class file present in two jars . One is test jar and the other is main jar. When both jars are used in one context and when the main jar executes, the test jar class file is picked up and the package object is searched within test jar .

Answer (score 0):

A package object should go in a file called package.scala and have the name of the package it is within. For example in file com/foo/bar/package.scala:

```
package com.foo

package object bar {
  ...
}
```